# I can't turn off "Easy Mode" on Galaxy On5 and there are missing options in the "Settings" Menu

Tags: samsung-galaxy-on5

I really need help here. I accidentally turned on my sister's "Ultra Power Save Mode" and, when I had realized I had done this, I turned it off. When the phone rebooted on again, it asked me what kind of set up I wanted, and me not knowing what it was talking about, selected one of the options and now it's stuck on "Easy Mode", but the apps are limited and there are missing options from the "SETTINGS" menu. I'm at my wits end and I'm afraid I might have to buy her a new phone. If anyone could answer me, that'd be amazingly helpful...

Answer (score 1):

From [Samsung Galaxy S5: How to Disable Easy Mode in Android 4.4.2 Kitkat](http://inside-galaxy.blogspot.com/2014/07/samsung-galaxy-s5-how-to-disable-easy.html):

> Method #1: From the notifications panel
>
> 1. Swipe down the top of the screen to open up the notifications panel.
> 2. Tap **the gear**(1) to go to the easy settings menu.
> 3. In Easy settings, tap Easy mode .
> 4. Tap Standard mode to select it.
> 5. Tap Done button.
>
> The easy mode will be disabled and the standard mode will be applied in your phone.

(1) Added emphasises due to original article has a picture instead of text.

> Method #2:
>
> From the Easy settings shortcut in Home screen
>   By default, you can find the easy settings in the Home screen in easy mode as an app and you can use it to access the easy settings menu to disable easy mode. See the following steps to disable easy mode:
>   From the main Home screen, swipe the screen from right to the left until you see the Easy settings shortcut/icon  and then tap it to go to the easy settings menu.
>
> 1. Tap Easy mode .
> 2. Tap Standard mode to select it.
> 3. Tap Done button.
>      The easy mode will be disabled and the standard mode will be applied in your phone.
>
> If in the easy mode you'll be provided with a simpler layout and the easy settings menu, then in the standard mode you'll be provided with a conventional layout and more complex settings menu. Also, in the standard mode, you can find and use all features owned by this phone unless you disable them.